# Store generated ImageMagick image to s3 without temp files

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, imagemagick, meteor, graphicsmagick

I am generating a PNG on the server side of a node.js application, using ImageMagick and the gm library for node.js ([GraphicsMagick for node.js](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/)).

```
// start with a blank image
var gmImage = gm(100, 100, "#000000ff");

// Draw the stuff on the new blank image
```

When I'm finished drawing stuff using the `gm` library, I am storing that image to the file system:

```
gmImage.write(imagePath, function (err) {
  ...
});
```

I am now moving to s3.  I want to skip this previous step and write the image direct to s3 without using a temporary file.

Is there a way to write the `gmImage` to a buffer or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the stream section of the API: https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#streams

You should be able to pipe stdout into s3

```
var gmImage = gm(100, 100, "#000000ff");
gmImage.stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  stdout.pipe(s3Stream);
});
```

Comment: how do you create that `s3Stream`? `fs.createWriteStream("[s3url]");` ?  I don't know why I can't find an example of creating a write stream to s3.

Comment: Using knox, https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox you can use a putStream.  `client.putStream(stdout, '/image.png', function (err, res) { . . . });`